# how to get prepared statement output in another variable in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want code which get scalar result value from prepared statement and store to another variable.
I don't want to execute that query which is prepared by prepared statement.
I want to stored the output get by prepared statement to variable so that I can use it in another query.

I want to use code like this:

```
set @lang='select ....';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @lang;
  SET @output=EXECUTE stmt;
select @output;
```

Comment: you can use into variable name to get the query or you can run that query to generate temporary table & use it :-)

Comment: how to code for that .. please give me example ; i am new in mysql

Comment: yes I got it, Thanks :)